# datatables fnfilter search issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a a column udner callerID and two rows under that column has
"MADOX EID" <+14791395555>
+14797195555

Two seperate rows when i search with a input of 555 or 147 the second row shows up just fine though the first one should show up as well.

$('#table_id').dataTable().fnFilter(searchpattern, dropdownindex + 1, false, true, true, true);

That is my fnfilter search, input from a form is searchpattern and the column chosen to search is in the dropdownindex, all of which works fine. Its the searching thats broken. I need it to search as a contains. as in both rows contain 555 and 147 but yet only the second row shows up.

```
    $('#csearchtext').bind("change paste keyup", function () {

    var input = $('#csearchtext').val();
    var dropdownindex = $("select[name='columnlist'] option:selected").index();
    var radioselected = $("input:radio[name='group2']:checked").val();
    var searchpattern = '';

    switch (radioselected) {
        case '1':
            searchpattern = '^' + input;
             $('#table_id').dataTable().fnFilter(searchpattern, dropdownindex + 1, true, false, true, true);
            break;
        case '2':
            searchpattern = input;
             $('#table_id').dataTable().fnFilter(searchpattern, dropdownindex + 1, false, true, true, true);
            break;
        case '3':
            searchpattern = input + '$';
             $('#table_id').dataTable().fnFilter(searchpattern, dropdownindex + 1, true, false, true, true);
            break;
    }
    console.log(searchpattern);
});
```

Any Advice ?
If i search EID it pulls the first row fine, but its like it has a problem with letters and numbers. To make matters worse is the search works fine in chrome but not in firefox or ie. I get both records in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the data in the aocolumn was either filtering on numeric or string not both, so making a stype: string on that column made it always look at a string.